# Running MR code for loading data into HBASE

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bulk-load

i am new to HBASE i am trying to load a data into HBASE from HDFS but i am not able to whenever i run MR i get same

error " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration"

all class files are there i am not understanding what is wrong .To run MR  first i compiled sourcecode and included hadoop and hbase libraries in classpath then i made jar and run it its giving same error.i tried the command

"hbase HBaseTemperatureImporter input" then it gives error as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HBaseTemperatureImporter"

this is also not working.Can anyone suggest me what is wrong ? is there any problem with hbase installation or missed any step while running MR for Hbase.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this means that your class is not in the classpath.

first of all check that your jar contains this class, you can list all the contents by doing:

`jar -tf <yourjar.jar>`

The class must be there, if it isn't you'll need to review your build process. In case it's there, just try adding this line in your hadoop job configuration:

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "dump to hbase");
job.setJarByClass(YourClassName.class);
```

Comment: i checked my .jar file class file is there.

Comment: ok, have you tried to add this two lines of code inside your main job configuration?

Comment: tried so many things nothing is working :(

Comment: i came across the same question!  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration this message has troubled me for a long time !